# SPARQL RDF prefixing

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs, turtle-rdf

Im wondering why I get a huge prefix on everything that is queried with SPARQL from my own ontology?

I'm quite new to all this, so I'm probably doing something wrong, but running this query

```
base <http://kasperrt/interests.ttl#>
prefix interests: <http://kasperrt.no/interests.ttl>

SELECT DISTINCT ?class ?s ?a
WHERE {
  ?s a ?class .
}
LIMIT 25
OFFSET 0
```

Why is everything prefixed with things like this
http://www.semanticweb.org/kasperrt/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-7?

And why won't this query return anything?

```
base <http://kasperrt/interests.ttl#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix interests: <http://kasperrt.no/interests.ttl>

SELECT DISTINCT ?interest1 ?interest2 ?name1 ?name2
WHERE {
    ?interest1
        rdfs:label ?name1;
        interests:Location ?location1.

    ?interest2
        rdfs:label ?name2;
        interests:Location ?location2.


  filter(?location1 != ?location2)

}
```

Comment: Ehm, because you created the ontology with this namespace? What do you expect to get as result of the query if your ontology contains classes with this namespace? I guess you know that entities like classes, properties, and individuals in a property are identified by URIs.

Comment: And what is `?a` in your first query? You can only select variables, `a` in a triple pattern is a shortcut for `rdf:type`, thus, not a variable.

Comment: The second query returns nothing because it doesn't match the data...which we don't know. And the prefix declaration is for sure wrong. You said the namespace is `http://www.semanticweb.org/kasperrt/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-7`, so why do you use another namespace here? The namespace is not the file name if your ontology uses the other prefix as you already recognized from your first query.

Comment: I don't know how you created the ontology, but I*d guess that the prefix eclaration in your second query should be `prefix interests: 
 <http://www.semanticweb.org/kasperrt/ontologies/2017/10/untit‌​led-ontology-7#>`

Comment: @Kasper, I suppose your ontology was created using Protégé. You can change ontology IRI in the [*Ontology Header* view](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/views/ontology-header/) (on the *Active Ontology* tab) or from *Refactor > Change Ontology IRI*. Protégé will asks you, would you also like to rename ontology entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as AKSW said, that the prefix declaration was defined wrong thus not returning any results in the query.

The onotology IRI wasn't specified in the query. Remember to refactor with when using Protégé correctly (as Stanislav Kralin said).